# jsf cascading drop down by using ajax not working

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am trying to implement cascading drop down in JSF. listing down the things that i did below please help me

XHTML code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country_id}" id="countries">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select a Country -- " itemValue="0"/>  
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" var="country" id="countryList"/>
         <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.getCityList}" execute="countries" render="cityList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>  

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.city_id}" id="cities">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select a City -- " itemValue="0"/>    
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.cities}" var="city" id="cityList" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The call is going to getCityList once we change the country and we are getting the countries value int that method too but  the list returned in the getcitylist is not getting applied to the cityList and the xhtml is throwing error.

Please help me in this regard

Thanks
KK

Answer (score 0):

Use `render="cities"` in `f:ajax`. You have to rerender the whole `selectOneMenu` to see the updated list in the view.